# Is the polynomial irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the polynomial $f = t^3 - t^2 + t + 2$ irreducible in ${\mathbb Q}[t]$? Can someone give me a hint how to figure it out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  Being a cubic, $f(t)$ is reducible if and only if it has a linear factor $t-(p/q)$.  And in this case $p$ must divide the constant term of $f(t)$, and $q$ must divide the leading coefficient, so there are only a small number of possibilities: you will easily either rule them all out or find one that works.